# How to keep graphics not moving when map zoom or pan in ArcGIS Andriod SDK

Tags: android, arcgis

It is just like the Uber to locate where it is

[graphic keep fixed position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRkM.gif)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To keep a point graphic in the fixed position of map window when drag the map window.